# Wrong result calling Android method from Delphi

Tags: android, delphi

I'm trying to call Android's class `GeomagneticField` method `getDeclination()` from my Delphi 10.2.3 app.

First I imported the class GeomagneticField using Java2OP:

```
unit Androidapi.JNI.Interfaces.JGeomagneticField;
interface
uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes;
type
// ===== Forward declarations =====
  JGeomagneticField = interface;//android.hardware.GeomagneticField
// ===== Interface declarations =====
  JGeomagneticFieldClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{77F2155B-1F9A-40E0-89FA-FE3422336577}']
    {class} function init(gdLatitudeDeg: Single; gdLongitudeDeg: Single; altitudeMeters: Single; timeMillis: Int64): JGeomagneticField; cdecl;
    {class} function getHorizontalStrength: Single; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function getInclination: Single; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function getX: Single; cdecl;//Deprecated
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/hardware/GeomagneticField')]
  JGeomagneticField = interface(JObject)
    ['{47CF41EC-AAAB-4EE2-867A-884A3EF00407}']
    function getDeclination: Single; cdecl;//Deprecated
    function getFieldStrength: Single; cdecl;//Deprecated
    function getY: Single; cdecl;
    function getZ: Single; cdecl;
  end;
  TJGeomagneticField = class(TJavaGenericImport<JGeomagneticFieldClass, JGeomagneticField>) end;

implementation

initialization
end.
```

Then I called the method this way:

```
procedure TForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var GeoField: JGeomagneticField; tm:int64; t0,t:TDatetime; 
begin
  t0 := EncodeDatetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0);
  t  := now;
  tm := Trunc( (t-t0)*24*3600*1000);   // <-- ms since 1/1/1970

  GeoField := TJGeomagneticField.JavaClass.init(-23,-46,750,tm );
  Label1.Text := FloatToStr( GeoField.getDeclination );
end;
```

When I run this and click, Label1 shows -174.3635711, which is wrong

On Android Studio I built a similar app in Java:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowDecl);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            GeomagneticField geoField = new GeomagneticField(
                    (float) -23,
                    (float) -46,
                    (float) 750,
                    System.currentTimeMillis()
            );
            float f = geoField.getDeclination();
            String s = Float.toString(f);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });
}
```

When I run this and click the button, I got -21.839144, which is correct.

**Why is my Delphi app getting this wrong result?**

Comment: Is your Delphi code giving you the same value for "tm"  as `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: I checked that. There is a small difference of about 9 hours ( I don't know why ). But this should not be the problem, as the value of the Declination changes very slowly

Comment: tm in java=1542392421545 in delphi=1542425646678

Comment: This is a great question and deserves more upvotes.

Comment: Interesting that the result for my test location is almost exactly 8x as much. But this is a coincidence, the factor is different for other locations..

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` is the number of milliseconds from the Unix epoch to the current time **in UTC**, but Delphi's `Now()` returns a `TDateTime` expressed in **local time** instead. So, you need to convert the local time to UTC before you can then calculate the milliseconds from the Unix epoch. Also, you really should not do things like `Trunc( (t-t0) ...)` for `TDateTime`, that performs floating-point arithmetic that can skew the results. Use `System.DateUtils.MilliSecondsBetween()` instead, which uses `TTimeStamp` internally for more accurate date/time calculations.

Comment: Note, Delphi's RTL has a `System.DateUtils.DateTimeToUnix()` function to convert a `TDateTime` to a Unix timestamp, but it has seconds precision (it uses `SecondsBetween()` internally), but it would be very easy to copy it and adjust it to use milliseconds instead.

Comment: Passing any time larger than 360 will give a negative result smaller than the correct -21.83 (  and -174.36 for current time).  It seems something funny is happening to the int64 parameter. Are Java long and Delphi int64 the same ?

Comment: The same question was asked in this post:
https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=118226

Comment: The problem was to be corrected in Rio  :)

Answer (score 2):

I narrowed the problem to the "timeMillis" parameter.
It is a Java long, which corresponds to Delphi's int64.
I suspected of some kind of endian problem, so I 
tried to switch the long parameter high and lo dwords.

And it **worked** !

```
function switchDWords(n:int64):int64;    // switch hi <--> lo dwords of an int64
var i: Integer;
    nn :int64; nnA:array[0..7]  of byte absolute nn;
    nn1:int64; nn1A:array[0..7] of byte absolute nn1;
begin
  nn1 := n;           // copy n
  for i := 0 to 3 do  // switch bytes  hidword <--> lodword
    begin
      nnA[i]   := nn1A[i+4];
      nnA[i+4] := nn1A[i];
    end;
  Result := nn;
end;

procedure TForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var GeoField: JGeomagneticField; tm:int64;  aD:Single; 
begin
  tm := System.DateUtils.DateTimeToUnix( Now, {InputAsUTC:} false )*1000;  

  tm := switchDWords(tm);    // <--  hack tm

  GeoField := TJGeomagneticField.JavaClass.init({Lat:}-23, {Lon:}-46, {Alt:}750, tm );
  aD := GeoField.getDeclination();   // <-- this shows -21.8416 which is correct !
  Label1.Text := FloatToStr( aD );
end;
```

Java2OP translation seems to be ok, so I wonder where the problem is.
Anyway, passing this hacked int64 parameter fixed it.

Comment: This problem was fixed in Rio

Comment: Hum.. Not really fixed. In D10.4.1 the hack is needed for 32b version, not for 64b.

    {$IFDEF CPUARM32}   tm := switchDWords(tm);    {$ENDIF CPUARM32}